# Execute a shell script everyday at specific time

Tags: linux, shell, cron, debian, sh

I have a simple shell script that just checks the contents of a directory and if anything was added during the day makes a copy of it to a backup folder.
I'd like to execute this script at the end of each day (let's assume at 23:55).

The system(Debian) which this scripts reside on it, is always on (kind of server)

How can I do that?

Comment: [You are looking for cron](http://www.debian-tutorials.com/crontab-tutorial-cron-howto)

Comment: read man crontab first

Comment: Most likely, there is already a question which asks the substantially the same question.

Comment: Careful: If you have a long-running script, you might have many instances running per day.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You want to edit your crontab file using

```
crontab -e
```

Then you want to add

```
55 23 * * * COMMAND TO BE EXECUTED
```

for more info look at [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20151226000333/http://www.debian-tutorials.com/crontab-tutorial-cron-howto)

Comment: file not found error from your link. You might want to update that

Answer (score 59):

To add a crontab job, type the following command at a UNIX/Linux shell prompt:

```
$ sudo crontab -e
```

Add the following line:

```
1 2 3 4 5 /path/to/script
```

where

```
1: Minutes (0-59)
2: Hours (0-23)
3: Days (1-31)
4: Month (1-12)
5: Day of the week(1-7)
/path/to/script - your own shell script
```

In your case it would be:

```
55 23 * * * /path/to/yourShellScript
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm anything, but a linux expert, but a quick Google search conjured up this:

```
watch -n <your time> <your command/script>
```

This should do the trick. For more information, check this out: http://www.linfo.org/watch.html

Comment: Thanks! I'll go with cron

Answer (score 4):

`sudo crontab -e`

```
55 23 * * * some_shell_script.sh
```

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [Cron](https://www.debian-administration.org/article/56/Command_scheduling_with_cron) task scheduler built in to Debian. Simply add an entry for your script to your crontab file (see: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto).