# How can I run a Python script remotly?

Tags: python, azure, google-cloud-platform, cloud

I made a Python script for Twitter using the Twitter API. It reads and writes to files, but small sized text files, only a few hundred lines of text, like 30kB.

I have been running this script on my computer for a while now, but I would prefer to have it run somewhere else and at specific times of the day. How can I do that?

Are there any free options for me to run the script remotly?

Comment: Have you considered running a command script via SSH that runs your files at a specific time of the day?

Comment: Nearly every Linux (or other UNIX like) server has a cron system that can schedule program runs.

Comment: i just started programming, I looked what you mentioned but I simply don't understand it, I'm sorry, would you mind explaining that in a little more detail? @Ehsan

Comment: There are standard procedures for it. It also depends on the system you are trying to execute your script too. These links seems helpful:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34753831/execute-a-shell-script-everyday-at-specific-time/34754109    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18945669/how-to-run-a-script-at-a-certain-time-on-linux

Answer (score 1):

> I have been running this script on my computer fora while now, but I
>   would prefer to have it run somewwhere else and at specific times of
>   the day. How can I do that?

You can run this script as `Azure Function` that gets triggered at specific times. You can learn more about timer triggered functions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=csharp.

> Are there any free options for me to run the script remotly?

Check out the pricing for Azure Functions here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/functions/. I think it is virtually free.

Comment: what are azure functions? I looked it up but could not understand it sorry. I'm a begginer in programming ahah

Comment: You may find these links helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/ and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/paths/create-serverless-applications/.

Comment: FYI the original question is off-topic, as they're asking for tool/product recommendations (and also tagged multiple clouds). There's no specific programming question to be answered...

Comment: i was asking how this all works, i know nothing about cloud computing, but i have a feeling thats where i should go to... as i said i am new to this... there is no need to downvote my post @DavidMakogon

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the right place to ask how this all works. May be you came here too soon :).